# Why is StaleElementReferenceException being thrown in following method?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following method used to click some dropdowns on a page:

```
protected void selectIthElementOffAllDropDowns(String selectElement, int entryOfDropdown) {

    ICollection<IWebElement> allElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(selectElement));

    foreach(IWebElement element in allElements) {
        if(element.IsDisplayed) {
            new SelectElement(element).SelectByIndex(entryOfDropdown);
        } 
    }
}
```

Around 70% of the time the code executes as expected. However, it occasionally throws a `StaleElementReferenceException`. When this is thrown it is thrown at the line:

```
new SelectElement(element).SelectByIndex(entryOfDropdown);
```

What I do not understand is how the `element.IsDisplayed` is true, yet according to the Selenium documentation [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) this error is thrown when The element has been deleted entirely or when the element is no longer attached to the DOM. Would anyone be able to explain how this error has been thrown? Additionally, why the condition in the if statement was true if this error was thrown correctly?

**Note:** I am using chromedriver to run these tests with OpenQA.Selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when the page reloads between finding the element and doing an action on it.

Always make sure element is there before doing any action.

In this case you are using `foreach` to do some actions with a list/array/collection of objects, if at any point the page is loaded then those objects are lost, they are not seen as attached to the page.

The issue is that the page changes state or reloads after you found the object => you have an object that is not attached to the page and you cannot use it. if you have multiple objects and you loop trough them then the chance of stale element will have a higher rate.

I don't know how correct the following example is: let assume you have an object of the page / an instance of the page, you search some element and you have the object(s) of the element, page reloads => instance is lost and new one is created, now you have some objects that do not be log to the page object, they are not attached to this page, similar elements are there, but not your objects, you will have to find and create new objects for your elements(s).

It can change at any time, including after the `if` condition is evaluated and enters in the `if`.